# mathematical operations using php scripting

Tags: php, sql

I am implementing k- nearest neighbor alog using euclidian distance formula for 2-D data in my sql table. Things look ok below even it shows strange behavious.

Code:

```
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT pcount, ncount from test");
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT pcount, ncount from test");
    $i = 0;
    $min = 0;
    while ($row1 = @mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
    {
        $pcount = $row1['pcount'];
        $ncount = $row1['ncount'];
        echo "pcount is $pcount<br/>";
        echo "ncount is $ncount<br/></br>";
        $a[$i] = $pcount ;
        $b[$i] = $pcount ;
        $j = 0;
        while ($row2 = @mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
        {
            echo "j is $j <br/>";
            $a[$j] = $row2['pcount'];   
            $b[$j] = $row2['ncount'];
            $diff = sqrt(($a[$i] - $a[$j])^2 + ($b[$i] - $b[$j])^2 );
        $j= $j + 1;
        echo "$diff <br>";
        }               
        echo "i is $i <br/>";
                $i = $i + 1;    
    }
```

it gives this result:

```
j is 0 
Difference : 0 
j is 1 
Difference : 1.4142135623731 
j is 2 
Difference : 0 
j is 3 
Difference : 0 
j is 4 
Difference : 1.4142135623731 
j is 5 
Difference : 1.4142135623731 
j is 6 
Difference : 1.4142135623731 
i is 0
```

In table I have total 8 rows, but above result is for 7 rows only. Why?

And First while loop gets executed for `$i = 0` on, for rest i=1 to 7 no operation. Can some one tell me what is bug?

data in table is

```
pcount  ncount
20  80
21  79
20  80
21  79
19  81
20  80
20  80
20  80
```

result after fallens answer:

```
j is 0 
Difference : 0 
j is 1 
Difference : NAN 
j is 2 
Difference : 0 
j is 3 
Difference : NAN 
j is 4 
Difference : 1.4142135623731 
j is 5 
Difference : 0 
j is 6 
Difference : 0 
j is 7 
Difference : 0 
i is 0 
pcount is 21
ncount is 79

i is 1 
pcount is 20
ncount is 80

i is 2 
pcount is 21
ncount is 79

i is 3 
pcount is 19
ncount is 81

i is 4 
pcount is 20
ncount is 80

i is 5 
pcount is 20
ncount is 80

i is 6 
pcount is 20
ncount is 80

i is 7
```

Comment: Could it fail because you used the same variable in both while-loops? Try replacing the $row in the second loop with something like $row2.

Comment: @mnme: thanks but no changes

Comment: why dont you print j on second while? it can give a clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same variable in inner and outer loop. Try different variable names for `row`s and `result`s in these two loops. Like `result1`, `row1` for outer and `result2`, `row2` for inner loop

It shows 7 rows instead of 8, because first row from `result` is picked by outer loop already

Try this piece of code:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT pcount, ncount from test");
$i = 0;
$min = 0;
while ($row1 = @mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $pcount = $row1['pcount'];
    $ncount = $row1['ncount'];
    echo "pcount is $pcount<br/>";
    echo "ncount is $ncount<br/></br>";
    $a[$i] = $pcount ;
    $b[$i] = $pcount ;
    $j = 0;

    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT pcount, ncount from test");

    while ($row2 = @mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        echo "j is $j <br/>";
        $a[$j] = $row2['pcount'];   
        $b[$j] = $row2['ncount'];
        $diff = ($a[$i] - $a[$j])^2 + ($b[$i] - $b[$j])^2;
        if( $diff != 0)
        $diff = sqrt( $diff );
    $j= $j + 1;
    echo "$diff <br>";
    }               
    echo "i is $i <br/>";
            $i = $i + 1;    
}
```

**Note** To avoid `NaN`, make sure `($a[$i] - $a[$j])^2 + ($b[$i] - $b[$j])^2` doesn't yield 0.

Comment: @Programming_crazy: I've added code. Please note that instead of initializing `$result2` once, this updated code initialize it for every possible outer loop

Comment: can you please suggest me to encount `($a[$i] - $a[$j])^2 + ($b[$i] - $b[$j])^2`, bcoz my data has frequent value where it yields 0

Comment: If you check the updated code, you can see this part `$diff = ($a[$i] - $a[$j])^2 + ($b[$i] - $b[$j])^2;
        if( $diff != 0)
        $diff = sqrt( $diff );` filters `$diff`